# I want to make backup of my app in android like Whatsapp

Tags: android, google-drive-api, backup, google-drive-android-api

I want to make a backup of my app in Android and I want it to be uploaded onto Google Drive as WhatsApp does. But I couldn't find any way to do this as the `Drive.DriveApi` method is deprecated now.

Please help me with new code.

Answer (score 2):

Google has provided samples of using Drive Rest API [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration/DriveServiceHelper.java).

For the detailed description, you can check this [medium post](https://ammar.lanui.online/integrate-google-drive-rest-api-on-android-app-bc4ddbd90820).

Answer (score 0):

The feature they are using is the same api as normal google drive, but using a special hidden folder. You could refer to this documentation on the details: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata

This is one of their examples:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/java-samples/blob/main/drive/snippets/drive_v3/src/main/java/UploadAppData.java

```
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
// [START drive_upload_appdata]

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Class to demonstrate use-case of create file in the application data folder.
 */
public class UploadAppData {

  /**
   * Creates a file in the application data folder.
   *
   * @return Created file's Id.
   */
  public static String uploadAppData() throws IOException {
        /*Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
        TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
        guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.*/
    GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
      credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
          .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
        credentials);

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        requestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("Drive samples")
        .build();
    try {
      // File's metadata.
      File fileMetadata = new File();
      fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
      fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
      java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
      File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
          .setFields("id")
          .execute();
      System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
      return file.getId();
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
      System.err.println("Unable to create file: " + e.getDetails());
      throw e;
    }
  }

}
// [END drive_upload_appdata]
```